# Use AVG result in select subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

I have a rating system in my app. Now I'm trying to get all AVG results from the ratings. Every AVG result has a result (in text) that I need to grab from the `rating_results` table.

It looks like this:

```
select round(avg(rating_results.rating)) as ratingresult, count(*) as votes, score.question_nl,
(select result_nl from rating_results where rating_results.rating = ratingresult and rating_results.score_id = score.id) from score 
inner join score_categories on score_categories.id = score.category_id
inner join rating ON score.id = rating.score_id
inner join rating_results on rating.rating_result_id = rating_results.id
inner join dog on dog.id = rating.ratable_id 
where dog.breed_id = 201
group by score.question_nl
```

The problem I have is that I cannot use `ratingresult` in the `subselect`.

> Query 1 ERROR: Reference 'ratingresult' not supported (reference to
>   group function)

I already tried a lot but can't figure out another way.

Could use some help here, thanks!

--EDIT

The rating result explains the rating. So if the AVG rating is 4 then in the rating_results table I can find what that rating means:

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and explain why the rating is a string and not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a select for column value you could use a subquery for avg in join

```
  select t.ratingresult
  , count(*) as votes
  , score.question_nl
  , rating_results.result_nl 
FROM score
inner join score_categories on score_categories.id = score.category_id
inner join rating ON score.id = rating.score_id
inner join rating_results on rating.rating_result_id = rating_results.id
inner join dog on dog.id = rating.ratable_id 
INNER JOIN  (
  select round(avg(rating_results.rating)) as ratingresult
    , score.question_nl
  from score 
  inner join rating ON score.id = rating.score_id
  inner join rating_results on rating.rating_result_id = rating_results.id
  group by score.question_nl
) t ON t.ratingresult = rating_results.rating   
        AND rating_results.score_id = score.id
          AND score.question_nl = t.question_nl
where dog.breed_id = 201
group by score.question_nl, t.ratingresult
```

avoinding subquery

Comment: Great! but I get this `Query 1 ERROR: Unknown column 'rating_results.rating' in 'having clause'` any idea?

Comment: `Query 1 ERROR: Unknown column 'rating_results.rating' in 'field list'` it looks like that cannot be used within the inner join.

Comment: @Jenssen  ... i'm sorry  .. is not my day  .. added missing join  ..  hope is useful

Comment: Thanks working now! You only forgot the select from `score` in the beginning! Thanks!!

Comment: @Jenssen   it's just like I said before .. it's not my day .. from score added  .. thanks